# Howto model relations between relations in a graph database?

Tags: neo4j

This seems to be a weird question - and maybe it is.

**Example:**

I have users, countries and roles.
The users are in one or more roles for one or more countries.

```
Sebastian -> Germany -> TaskVerifier
                     -> QuestionApprover
          -> Austria -> TaskVerifier
                     -> Worker
                     -> Whatever
```

The respective roles have different permissions...

How do I have to model this? (For example in neo4j)

Setting relations between users and roles with a country attribute does not seem to be the solution because I also need country nodes in other relations.

Comment: Relevant blog post/tutorial : https://maxdemarzi.com/2013/03/18/permission-resolution-with-neo4j-part-1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something that can do the glue between your country & role nodes.
In my example, I called it `Permission`.

Here is a little cypher script to create your dummy graph :

```
// Country
CREATE (c1:Country { name:'Germany'}
CREATE (c2:Country { name:'Austria'}

// Roles
CREATE (r1:Role { name:'TaskVerifier'})
CREATE (r2:Role { name:'QuestionApprover'})
CREATE (r3:Role { name:'Worker'})
CREATE (r4:Role { name:'Whatever'})

// Users
CREATE (u:User{name:'Sebastien'})

CREATE (p1:Permission)
CREATE (u)-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->(p1)
CREATE (r1)<-[:HAS_ROLE]-(p1)-[:FOR_CONTRY]->(c1)

CREATE (p2:Permission)
CREATE (u)-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->(p2)
CREATE (r2)<-[:HAS_ROLE]-(p2)-[:FOR_CONTRY]->(c1)

CREATE (p3:Permission)
CREATE (u)-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->(p3)
CREATE (r1)<-[:HAS_ROLE]-(p3)-[:FOR_CONTRY]->(c2)

CREATE (p4:Permission)
CREATE (u)-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->(p3)
CREATE (r3)<-[:HAS_ROLE]-(p4)-[:FOR_CONTRY]->(c2)

CREATE (p4:Permission)
CREATE (u)-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->(p4)
CREATE (r4)<-[:HAS_ROLE]-(p4)-[:FOR_CONTRY]->(c2)
```